# paracol: How to reset footnote counter every page?

Tags: paracol

Is there a way to reset the footnote counter every page without getting errors and warnings?

If I use `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}` I get an error.
If I use `\usepackage{perpage} \MakePerPage{footnote}` I get a warning.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

  \blindtext{1}

  \begin{paracol}{2} % left column
  \textbf{Hello, I'm column one.}\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
  \blindtext{1}
  \switchcolumn % right column
  \textbf{Hello, I'm column two.}\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
  \blindtext{1}
  \end{paracol}

  \blindtext{1}

  \blindtext{1}

  \begin{paracol}{2} % left column
  \textbf{Hello, I'm column one.}\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
  \blindtext{1}
  \switchcolumn % right column
  \textbf{Hello, I'm column two.}\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
  \blindtext{1}
  \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414513/paracol-how-to-reset-footnote-counter-every-page-worst-case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found an easy solution:

```
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\setcounter{footnote}{0}} % resets footnote counter on every page
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}

\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

  \blindtext{1}

  \begin{paracol}{2} % left column
  \textbf{Hello, I'm column one.}\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
  \blindtext{1}
  \switchcolumn % right column
  \textbf{Hello, I'm column two.}\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
  \blindtext{1}
  \end{paracol}

  \blindtext{1}

  \blindtext{1}

  \begin{paracol}{2} % left column
  \textbf{Hello, I'm column one.}\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
  \blindtext{1}
  \switchcolumn % right column
  \textbf{Hello, I'm column two.}\footnote{I'm a footnote.}
  \blindtext{1}
  \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```