# Paracol package creates \endcsname error with footnotes

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, tabularx, enumitem, paracol

TeXShop 4.01

Default Command: LaTeX

Default Script: Pdftex

Sync Method: SyncTex

Error message:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.  
<to be read again>
                   \protect
```

Occurs when trying to including \usepackage{paracol} and using a footnote. This is not the same issue as [paracol: How to reset footnote counter every page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306396/paracol-how-to-reset-footnote-counter-every-page) nor [Footnote problem using paracol package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97088/footnote-problem-using-paracol-package?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I have implemented the recommendation from [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97088/footnote-problem-using-paracol-package?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and it did not work (unless i did it wrong?)

MWE provided has been structured such that it includes 2 item lists, which are intended to be inside tcolorboxes that are placed side by side with the use of the paracol package. The lists are placed where a page break is required. They may not be in tables, which would render the lists unbreakable. They may not be in a single tcolorbox with the sidebyside functionality, which makes it the box unbreakable. They cannot be placed in tcolorbox rasters, which also become unbreakable. They cannot be in tcolorbox magazines because that required knowing, beforehand, where to break the lists. At this point, tcolorbox is not required, but does help me with spacing various things that go inside each separate column.

Image 1 presents the expected output with the footnotes.[image: with footnotes]

Image 2 presents the expected output with the side by side lists.[image: with side by side lists]

Paracol environment will occur multiple times thoughout, each without footnotes.The footnotes are not within any paracol environment, nor will they be.

At the moment, the MWE has the paracol related code commented out. I can either have a footnote or the side by side tables.

MWE requires a document class which is provided by my educational institution. Slightly modified version is available here: [It's a OneDrive link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuyobNouVLkpg-I8drwNC0x5FDzuFQ)

```
\documentclass[whitelogo]{tudelft-report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{url}               % to format urls
%\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[nomargin,inline,marginclue,draft]{fixme}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutInline[3]{%
  {\@fxuseface{inline}\ignorespaces[#3 \fxnotename{#1}: #2]}}
\makeatother
% Footnote fonts
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   %\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\small}{}{}
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{11}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{tasks}{
     enhanced jigsaw,
    enforce breakable,
     nobeforeafter,
     boxsep=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    pad at break*=0pt,
    colback=white,
    colframe=white,
    watermark color=white,
     width=.89\textwidth
     }
\newtcolorbox{est_time}{
     enhanced jigsaw,
    enforce breakable,
     nobeforeafter,
     boxsep=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    pad at break*=0pt,
    colback=white,
    colframe=white,
    watermark color=white,
     width=.11\textwidth,
}

\begin{document}
\listoffixmes
\mainmatter
\section{State of the Art}
\label{sec:State_of_the_Art}
\par{TEXT TEXT'\textit{Derp Derpy derp.}' \fxnote{Footnote Issue} \footnote{\url{https://www.google.com/}, accessed on 27 October 2017} \footnote{\url{https://www.wikipedia.org}, accessed on 27 October 2017}
}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\par{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, plac- erat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habi- tant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellusula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habi- tant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus}


\noindent\textbf{Work Package 1}\hrule
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
 {@{}%
   >{\setlength{\hsize}{.12\textwidth}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X%
   >{\setlength{\hsize}{.85\textwidth}}X%
   @{}}%   
  \textbf{Title:}      & Text \\
  \textbf{Objective:}  & \lipsum[1]\\
  \textbf{Required:}   & Text\\
  \textbf{Output:}     & More text.
\end{tabularx}
%\columnratio{0.89}
%\setlength{\columnsep}{0em}
%\begin{paracol}{2}
%\begin{leftcolumn}
\begin{tasks}
\textbf{Task List}
\begin{enumerate}[%
       label={WP.1.\arabic*},
       leftmargin=*,
       align=parleft,noitemsep]
\item Task 1.
\item Task 2.
\item Task 3.
\item Task 4.
\item Task 5.
\item Task 6.
\item Task 7.
\item Task 8.
\item Task 9.
\item Task 10.
\end{enumerate}
\end{tasks}
%\end{leftcolumn}
%%%---------------------------------------------
%\begin{rightcolumn}
\begin{est_time}%
\textbf{Est. Hrs}
\begin{enumerate}[%
       leftmargin=0pt,
       align=parleft,noitemsep]
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 1
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 2
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 3
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 4
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 5
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 6
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 7
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 8
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 9
\item[]\-\hspace{1em}Time 10
\end{enumerate}
\end{est_time}
%\end{rightcolumn}
%\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was unable to find tudelft-report.cls, but using book class uncommenting paracol worked fine.  Not sure what you were trying to accomplish with the right column enumerate, though.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Thanks for giving it a try and commenting! tudelft-report.cls is available in the OneDrive link in the post, and its here [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuyobNouVLkpg-I8drwNC0x5FDzuFQ).

I would love to be able to use a simple book class though, but Im somewhat bound to tudelft-report.cls. You telling be about the book class  does tell me I could use that to continue troubleshooting though.

Comment: Regarding the right column enumerate, it could be considered a 'hack'. I just want to be able to have the tasks and a value on the side, but each task must be itemized, allowing certain structure and referencing. Tables are quite rigid for nested lists, especially during pagebreaks.

I guess this could be somewhat visually considered like a table of contents, where you have a structured item list and a corresponding number at the right of each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps taken that resolved the issue:

Comment or remove the following from the preamble:

```
\usepackage{paracol}
```

Open tudelft-report.cls and place:

```
\RequirePackage{paracol}
```

This has to be placed BEFORE  the following:

```
\RequirePackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
```

This then led to some other issues with (present in tudelft-report.cls):

```
\RequirePackage[hyperfootnotes=false,pdftex,colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
```

along with associated setup options (also present in tudelft-report.cls):

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=title,
    linkcolor=title,
    urlcolor=title
}
```

Everything related to the hyperref package was removed from tudelft-report.cls, placed in the preamble, and no more issues came about.